# Backbone read JSON item and save to model

Tags: json, backbone.js

Hi I'm new to Backbone but have to solve a problem.

There is a working webapp - online shop. On the CartView browsers gets a JSON file from /lampy/api/filter.

I need to save it somehow into model because I need some value from it?

How should I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a little broad, please show what research you've done on this issue already, show your code so that people can check it and replicate the issue. This [link](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/) should help.

Comment: @kuba0506 Did the answer below resolve your issue? If so, could you mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your JSON object looks like:

```
{
    item1: 'some string',
    item2: 'another string',
    item3: 'and another'
}
```

When you say:

> to save it somehow into model

I'm assuming you mean instantiate a model with the values of your JSON object. To do this you can simply do:

```
var myModel = new Backbone.Model(yourJsonObject)
```

This will just be a plain Backbone Model without any Url so you won't be able to interact with the server with it, but as you said you need some value from it so you can use:

```
myModel.get('item1')    // returns 'some string'
```